# (UE4) Moving ball jumps unintendedly in places where geometry "connects". How do i fix this?

Tags: c++, game-physics, unreal-engine4

I am trying to make a very simple runner game, where a ball moves forward infinitely and your goal is to not let it bump into obstacles. I made a simple level with UE4 geometry, the ground is made out of different geometry objects. These objects are placed really close together, so there are, presumably, no gaps.

The engine is simulating physics for the ball.
I move this ball by executing this code every Tick:

```
FVector MoveForce(0, 1000000, 0);
BallMesh->AddTorqueInRadians(MoveForce);
```

I tried AddForce and AddImpulse before, they gave me the same result.

Here are the blueprint's components and Physics+Collision Details

[Blueprint Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MNa3.png)

The main problem is, in places where the geometry connects (also on non-flat geometry), the ball just jumps, like there is a trampoline. And I can't figure out why this is happening.

Here is an example of the ball moving forward (to the left relatively to us) and then just jumping up.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM5LI.png)

I tried using new physical materials, disabling PCMs, changing the level's geometry. Nothing changed regarding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try if increasing mass would help,

I think this is happening because in collision detection it is not always very smooth but discrete in nature

also see if there collision primitive doesn't miss-aligned to each other.

Comment: Increasing mass slowed it down and allowed for the ball to pass smoothly, however increasing speed makes the ball jumpy again. I tried clearing and generating (using UE tools) collision multiple times, with multiple options, didn't work, probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The force you gave to the ball is quite large. In reality for that force, the ball should jump high in places of contact...because there is an addition to the upward normal force.

Solution:
virtual void AddTorqueInRadians
(
FVector Torque,
FName BoneName,
bool bAccelChange
)

When calling the function **AddTorqueInRadians**, set the boolean value of **bAccelChange** to true and see. This will allow you to use less force, as here torque is taken as change in angular acceleration instead of physical torque (mass will have no effect). This should work.  And Bone Name is **none**.

Something like this:

FVector MoveForce(0, 20, 0);
BallMesh->AddTorqueInRadians(MoveForce, None, true);

Also, Uncheck MassInKg in blueprints for mesh.